# How to use "sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = []" in gradle experimental

Tags: gradle, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

in my gradle-build I have this istruction:

sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = []

but I need to migrate to gradle experimental (to be able to use breakpoints to debug native source), is there possible to use it in some way in gradle-experimental?

Thank you

Comment: No, because I need to debug c++ source using breakpoints, and to do that I have to use gradle experimental, without it debug doesn't stop to breakpoints

Comment: Have you looked at Google NDK samples on Github?  They demo gradle experimental.